# Need help figuring out this script to write to a floppy disk in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, music, floppy

I'm trying to run [the program described here](http://yceran.org/eps/) on Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm new to Linux and would very much appreciate help in making sense of this program to read/write floppy disks for my Ensoniq EPS16+ sampling keyboard.

the description of epsread says:

> epsread
>
> A shell script that uses `fdrawcmd` to read an EPS disk a track at a time. It spits the data out to stdout, so redirect it to a file. Warning: It doesn't check the disk is formatted correctly and it reads only from `/dev/fd0`.
>
> If you give it a parameter of write it instead writes an EPS disk. Redirect a file from stdin. The disk must already be formatted correctly -- it doesn't check that. And again, it also only writes to `/dev/fd0`.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
#
# File copyright Wade Bowmer, but you're free to use it as you like.
# 
# Be sure to have a look at http://yceran.org/eps/
# 

# Parameter checking CMD=read if [ "`basename $0`" == "epswrite" ] ; then CMD=write ; fi if [ "$1" == "read" ] ; then CMD=read ; fi if [
"$1" == "write" ] ; then CMD=write ; fi

# Do the actual work CYL=0 while [ $CYL -lt 80 ] ; do

    fdrawcmd $CMD 0 $CYL 0 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120 rate=2 track=$CYL

    # Second side   fdrawcmd $CMD 4 $CYL 1 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120
rate=2 track=$CYL

    CYL=$(( $CYL + 1 ))

done
```

I got the latest version of `fdutils` installed just fine. I just copied and pasted the epsread shell script into a terminal. Then it ran and I realized I have no idea what I am doing.

If someone could walk me through what this program is trying to do, I think that would help me form the next, more detailed questions I need to ask to step towards getting writing the files I have to a floppy disk in Ensoniq EPS16+ format.

If we can figure out how to get this program to work it will help lots of people who are on Linux with several different Ensoniq keyboards as they are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You have garbled the shell script. It should be:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
#
# File copyright Wade Bowmer, but you're free to use it as you like.
# 
# Be sure to have a look at http://yceran.org/eps/
# 

# Parameter checking 
CMD=read 
if [ "`basename $0`" == "epswrite" ] ; then CMD=write ; fi 
if [ "$1" == "read" ] ; then CMD=read ; fi 
if [ "$1" == "write" ] ; then CMD=write ; fi

# Do the actual work 
CYL=0 
while [ $CYL -lt 80 ] ; do

    fdrawcmd $CMD 0 $CYL 0 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120 rate=2 track=$CYL

    # Second side   
    fdrawcmd $CMD 4 $CYL 1 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120 rate=2 track=$CYL

    CYL=$(( $CYL + 1 ))

done
```

Here's how it works:

First, it sets the `CMD` local variable to "`read`".
Then, if the script's `basename` is `"epswrite"` it sets `CMD` to "`write`".
If the 1st parameter to the script is "`read`", `CMD` is set to "`read`".
If the 1st parameter to the script is "`write`", `CMD` is set to "`write`".

The local variable `CYL` is set to `0`.

The `CMD` and `CYL` variables will be used in generating the actual command to run.

A loop begins! As long as the condition `$CYL -lt 80` (The value of `CYL` is less than `80`) is true, the shell code between the `do` and the matching `done` will be repeated.

There are 3 commands in the loop. In the first two, interpolation of the values for `CMD` and `CYL` create the acutal commands used to execute the `fdrawcmd` (See `man fdrawcmd`). The first time through the loop, the commands will be:

```
fdrawcmd read 0 0 0 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120 rate=2 track=0 
fdrawcmd read 4 0 1 0 2 10 0x1b 0xff length=5120 rate=2 track=0
#....CMD.^^^^   ^ CYL                                         ^ CYL
```

The third command in the loop,

```
CYL=$(( $CYL + 1 ))
```

increments `CYL` by `1`. After a while, `$CYL -lt 80` will not be true, and the loop will end. Execution of the shell script will resume after the

```
done
```

line.

To find out what all those parameters to the `fdrawcmd` command are, read `man fdrawcmd` or [the online copy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/fdrawcmd.1.html)

Comment: There is also one formal thing. It should be `#!/bin/bash`. First because of the *space* between `#!` and `/bin/sh`. And then because *in POSIX sh, `==` is not supported.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the floppy patch is included in modern mainline kernels you can disregard this script and just user setfdprm/fdformat/dd

Check this out too:
http://www.buchty.net/ensoniq/

Bear in mind that EPS16+ uses DD disks so if you have HD disks you have to cover the hole.

In short you should do:

```
mknod /dev/fd0eps b 2 120
setfdprm /dev/fd0eps ds dd sect=10 zerobased
```

then you can just read/write EPS disks with dd i.e.:

```
dd if=/dev/fd0eps of=file.dd
```

you can also format them like

```
fdformat /dev/fd0eps
```